# Parse Server / Dashboard not showing mongoimport csv collections

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, mlab

I'm having some trouble with mongoimport and parse dashboard / server.

If I create a class on parse dashboard (pointing at mlab/heroku mongoDb), I can see the collection on mlab website.  If I then use mongochef to import a csv and add it to the collection, I can see the changes on mlab website, but not on parse dashboard.

If I don't create the class on parse dashboard, and create a new collection on mlab or in mongochef, it's not visible in parse dashboard.

Attempt 2, point parse dashboard at local mongo DB, tried importing a csv using mongoimport, nothing appears on dashboard.

I've got a hunch that it might be something to do with object ID's (parse format vs mongo format), but it seems that unless the class is created via parse dashboard, it won't look at it.

My classes have 30+ columns, and 2.5k rows - I used to use parse website import csv function - gutted that's gone!

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi , can you please check if you have values inside your _SCHEMA collection in mongoDB?

Comment: Interesting - the classes/collections that show up in parse dashboard are listed in _SCHEMA, the ones that don't are not.  Would this be something I'd need to edit manually with each import?

Comment: When you imported the collections you did it by looking on some docs or not?

Comment: So thanks to Ran Hassid - I've made some progress!  

I created the collection 'testSchema' on mlab website.
I edited the collection _SCHEMA and copied another entry, to have 3 columns:
`{
    "_id": "testSchema",
    "objectId": "string",
    "updatedAt": "date",
    "createdAt": "date",
    "TC1": "string",
    "TC2": "string",
    "TC3": "string",
    "image": "file"
}`

I used mongochef and uploaded a csv with 3 columns and 2 rows, column names the same as i've put in schema.

Success! It appears in parse dashboard. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RanHassid Lifesaver - forgot to add my class data to the `_SCHEMA` collection. (For anyone else: Note that if you do not add your table metadata to the schema, it will *not show up* in Parse Dashboard.) Thanks!

Comment: Happy that it works for you now :)